# Using JUnit in Jython - NameError for assertTrue

Tags: junit, jython, nameerror

**Environment Details**
Mac OS X 10.9
Oracle JDK 1.7.0_55 64-bit
jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar
junit-4.11

**What I have done so far**
I have added the junit jar to /Library/Java/Extensions.
I invoked Jython as follows `java -jar jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar`
In the Jython interpreter, I imported the following `import org.junit.Assert`, and this import was successful.

**Problem**
When I tried to use `assertTrue`, I got a `NameError` in the interpreter. Why is this so?

I understand that `assertTrue` is a static method. Not sure what implication this has when I try to use it in Jython.

**Additional Context**
I am using XMLUnit in Jython. Was able to successfully import the `Diff` class from `org.custommonkey.xmlunit` in Jython. Also able to use the methods in this class, and call them on a `Diff` object. The result of this method call is what I am trying to pass to `assertTrue`, when it throws the error.

```
from org.custommonkey.xmlunit import Diff
import org.junit.Assert

xml1 = ...some XML string...
xml2 = ...some XML string...

myDiff = Diff(xml1, xml2)
assertTrue(myDiff.similar())
```

Hope this additional information is useful in identifying a solution to this problem.

**Latest Status**
I narrowed it down to setting this property `python.security.respectJavaAccessibility = false`, since the `Assert()` constructor is `protected`.

Still trying to get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

In addition to `junit.jar` file, the `hamcrest-core.jar` file also needed to be copied to `/Library/Java/Extensions`.

Then I got rid of the `jython.jar` file, and instead installed it using the jython installer.

After the installation was completed, I updated the `registry` file in the installation folder, specifically setting this property `python.security.respectJavaAccessibility = false`.

Now I am able to see the `assertTrue` method, and no longer getting a `NameError`.